# Program demonstrating structures does not receive correct input values

Tags: c, structure

This simple program demonstrates the use of structures by determining tomorrow's date.  It asks for an input of today's date:

```
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    struct date {
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
    };  /* ----------  end of struct date  ---------- */

    struct date today, tomorrow;

    const int   daysPerMonth[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30,
                         31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    printf ( "Enter today's date (mm dd yyyy): \n" );
    scanf ( "%i%i%i", &today.month, &today.day, &today.year );

    if ( today.day != daysPerMonth[today.month - 1] ) {
        tomorrow.day = today.day + 1;
        tomorrow.month = today.month;
        tomorrow.year = today.year;
    }
    else if ( today.month == 12 ) {         /* end of year */
        tomorrow.day = 1;
        tomorrow.month = 1;
        tomorrow.year = today.year + 1;
    }
    else {                                  /* end of month */
        tomorrow.day = 1;
        tomorrow.month = today.month + 1;
        tomorrow.year = today.year;
    }

    printf ( "Tomorrow's date is %i/%i/%.2i.\n", tomorrow.month,
          tomorrow.day, tomorrow.year % 100 );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}       /* ----------  end of function main  ---------- */
```

When running it, what I got:

> Enter today's date (mm dd yyyy):
>
> ```
> 06 09 2014
> ```
>
> Tomorrow's date is 6/1/09.

But when I run gdb and printed out the input values:

```
(gdb) p today.month

$1 = 6

(gdb) p today.day

$2 = 0

(gdb) p today.year

$3 = 9
```

I'm confused.  Why is the input getting incorrect values like that?

Comment: Why is there this rash of beginners using `%i`? You almost always want `%d`, which always reads the number as decimal.

Comment: I typed this program out from the book "Programming in C", by Stephen Kochan.  This author uses %i pretty often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh. The `%i` specifier for `scanf` means to read in a range of integer formats which is similar to that specified for C integer literals.

When you type a leading `0` it means that what follows are **octal** digits. Since `9` is not a valid octal digit, then just the value `0` is read. The `9` is left for the following `%i`, so the three numbers read are `6`, `0`, `9` , with `2014` remaining in the input stream.

To input in base 10 change the `%i` to `%d`, then your program will work.

Comment: I just changed the format to %d and it worked now!  I understand now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You read the input as `scanf ( "%i%i%i", &today.month, &today.day, &today.year );`.

Since you prefix `0` in your input, they are treated as *octal* and thus lead to the result.

You should use `scanf("%d%d%d", ...);` instead.